# SQL conditional WHERE simplification

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I currently have a statement in my `WHERE` clause like this:

```
AND ((@includeExpired = 0 AND lic.[DateExpiresUtc] > GETDATE()) 
     OR 
     (@includeExpired = 1 AND lic.[DateExpiresUtc] <> GETDATE())
    )
```

Which just looks ugly, I've tried just including a simpler version of the statement like:

```
(@includeExpired = 0 AND lic.[DateExpiresUtc] > GETDATE())
```

But when `@includeExpired` is `1` it all fails to select anything.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Is the `<>` in `lic.[DateExpiresUtc] <> GETDATE()` a typo? 'cause that looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your variabel name `@includeExpired`, which implies that this variable decides about additionally including expired records in the result set, the check in the second part, `lic.[DateExpiresUtc] <> GETDATE()`, is not necessary and the other check in the first part is not necessary.

Try this:

```
AND (lic.[DateExpiresUtc] > GETDATE()) OR (@includeExpired = 1)
```

Comment: Looks right. `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` could give better plans in the case that `@includeExpired <> 1`

Comment: I would reverse the order of the items being OR'd to take advantage of short-circuiting. In the current ordering, the DateExpiresUtc field will be checked on every row and only looking at includeExpired if DateExpiresUtc <= GETDATE(). But if you switch the order and includeExpired is set to 1, then it will skip that check.  Example: SELECT 1 WHERE ((1 = 1) OR (1 / 0 = 5)); SELECT 1 WHERE ((1 = 0) OR (1 / 0 = 5))

Comment: @srutzky, modern database engines have extensive automated optimization, which would do this for you automatically. I know this at least about Oracle and MySQL. Does SQL Server 2012 not have such features?

Comment: @DanielS. - Correct. SQL Server will rearrange it as it sees fit anyway. The main problem here is that the plan it compiles will need to work for both cases which will prevent a possible index seek in the more selective case. Hence `RECOMPILE` suggestion.

Comment: @DanielS., I do not have Oracle to test on, but I would think most RDBMS's would allow for some level of short-circuiting and if they do, then I am not sure how an optimizer would be able to best determine the ordering since there can be multiple OR conditions, etc.  Try this updated example (replace double "@@" with "@"): DECLARE @@Test INT = 1; SELECT 1 WHERE ((@@Test = 1) OR (1 / 0 = 5)); SELECT 2 WHERE ((@@Test = 0) OR (1 / 0 = 5)); SELECT 3 WHERE ((1 / 0 = 5) OR (@@Test = 1))

Comment: @MartinSmith, I am pretty sure there is a difference between the query optimizer arranging JOINs as it sees fit (when not using OPTION FORCEORDER) as opposed to changing the order of boolean evaluation.

Comment: @srutzky - See [On SQL Server boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/). SQL is declarative. SQL Server can rearrange predicates and push them into different parts of the tree during optimization.

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks, I had forgotten about the distinction between parsing a query vs evaluating an IF / CASE / IIF / etc statement. Thanks for that link :).

Answer (score 0):

Just one idea.

```
(CASE
  WHEN @includeExpired = 1 THEN 1
  WHEN @includeExpired = 0 AND lic.[DateExpiresUtc] > GETUTCDATE() THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END) = 1
```